# How do I choose which thermodynamical potential to use to describe a phase transition?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

While studying thermodynamics I came across the Gibbs free energy and the Helmholtz free energy... **IF** I understand thing correctly, when describing a phase transition I can use any thermodynamical potential I want, or "the one that suits me best". But what I don't understand is, if I use a random potential, to describe the phase transition, how will others, know which TP I used? And can I even randomly create a TP that suits me best?